# Azure Web App for containers CI with Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, azure-container-service, azure-container-registry, azure-web-app-for-containers

I'm having an issue with Azure Container Registry CI with my Azure Web App for Containers. It seems that the web hook between them has broken. 
I've tried turning the CI within the Docker settings on the Web App however this fails and also tried creating a web hook from the Azure Container Registry however it says my container registry isn't managed but doesn't give me the option to upgrade it to one.

Comment: What is the exact error message you receive? 
You may try the steps mentioned here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Webhooks are not available in the classic SKU and you need to migrate for this. For CI you need to enable a webhook with the publishing creds which can call into the App service scm endpoint which can restart and repull.